# Wait until more conditions with RxJava on each external thread - do single operation across threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, async-await, rx-java

I need to create this:

[image: Desiderata diagram with RxJava]

Now I have a working solution for the creation of new threads and the resume on the main thread when all *signHash(..)* are completed on new threads. [See working code at the end of the post]

As you can see in the diagram, what I must create is a way to manage, on new separated threads, the "wait and resume functionallity" of a portion of the method *signHash(..)* that now is simulated with a sleep.

In particular, after  *String hash = doStuff(..)* that must be present on that position, I want to populate a bean like this:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class DocumentHashBucket {    
    private int numberNeededHashes;
    private boolean completedStoreHashes;
    private boolean completedStoreSignedHashes;
    private Map<String,byte[]> map = new Hashtable<>();
}
```

in order to store the hash created by *String hash = doStuff(..)* and when only all threads have done theirs *doStuff(..)* reaching the *numberNeededHashes* I must do only one time on a single thread the call to a cloud service on internet that sign hashes. When the signing hash on cloud is completed I'll could change the map with signed hashes and permit the resume of the *signHash(..)* that will execute the *doStuff2(signedHash);* and, after, close the method/thread.

**REQUIREMENT**: It is mandatory to call *doStuff(..)*  and *doStuff2(signedHash)* in that position and manage the single external cloud call between them.

**QUESTION**: How can I do it easily with RxJava?

Thanks a lot in advance

**Working code that I'm using:**

```
package com.example.unit;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class UTestRxJava {

    @Test
    void uRxJavaSimple() {

        // Create an iterable observables
        List<Integer> calls = new LinkedList<>();
        calls.add(1);
        calls.add(2);
        calls.add(3);
        calls.add(4);

        final BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        System.out.println("Starting parallel executions");

        // Create an iterable observables
        List<Observable<Integer>> observables = new LinkedList<>();
        for (final Integer i: calls) {
            System.out.println("Adding... "+i);
            observables.add(Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    return signHash(i);
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())); // subscribeOn => specify the Scheduler on which an Observable will operate
        }

        final Map<String,String> mapResults = new HashMap<>();

        Observable.zip(observables, new Function<Object[], Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Object[] objects) throws Throwable { // Zip observables
                System.out.println("apply()");
                List<String> observables = new LinkedList<>();
                for (Object obj:objects) {
                    System.out.println("Applying... "+obj.toString());
                    observables.add(obj.toString());
                }
                return observables;
            }
        })
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object results) throws Throwable {
                        System.out.println("Ending parallel executions");
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(Schedulers.from(new Executor() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
                        tasks.add(runnable);// Add a scheduler with executor from the current thread
                    }}))
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    // The Subscribe operator is the glue that connects an observer to an Observable
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object results) throws Throwable { // Subscribe to the result.
                        // Put your code that needs to "wait"
                        for (String x : (List<String>)results) {
                            System.out.println("Results: "+x);
                            mapResults.put(x,"OK");
                        }
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("[START] TAKE-RUN");
        try {
            tasks.take().run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();fail("it's not possible that there is an exception");}
        System.out.println("[END] TAKE-RUN");

        assertTrue(mapResults.size()==4);
    }

    private Integer signHash(Integer number) {
        String hash = doStuff(..)
        Integer result = number * number;
        System.out.println("Pre log \t"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"\t"+ result);
        try {
            // TODO chage it with List<Hash> signHashesOnInternet(List<Hash>) only on one of all threads
            Thread.sleep(number * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println("Post log \t"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"\t"+ result);
        doStuff2(signedHash);
        return result;
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Starting parallel executions
Adding... 1
Adding... 2
Adding... 3
Adding... 4
[START] TAKE-RUN
Pre log     RxNewThreadScheduler-1  1
Pre log     RxNewThreadScheduler-2  4
Pre log     RxNewThreadScheduler-3  9
Pre log     RxNewThreadScheduler-4  16
Post log    RxNewThreadScheduler-1  1
Post log    RxNewThreadScheduler-2  4
Post log    RxNewThreadScheduler-3  9
Post log    RxNewThreadScheduler-4  16
apply()
Applying... 1
Applying... 4
Applying... 9
Applying... 16
Ending parallel executions
Results: 1
Results: 4
Results: 9
Results: 16
[END] TAKE-RUN


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what I found and tested.
I don't know if this is the optimal solution but for me now it is working.

I used ***BehaviorSubject*** and his method ***blockingForEach*** in order to observe changes on the *DocumentHashBucket* (that is the bean that I created).

With this approach the *blockingForEach* allow me to have a blocking code that don't continue the execution of the rest of code until ***behaviorSubject.onComplete()*** is called.

```
package com.example.unit;

import com.example.DocumentHashBucket;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Action;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

public class UTestRxJavaStackOverflowSolution {

    @Test
    void uRxJavaSimple() {

        // Create an iterable observables
        List<Integer> calls = new LinkedList<>();
        calls.add(1);
        calls.add(2);
        calls.add(3);
        calls.add(4);

        // create the Observable that will be used for collect all hashes and store the signed version of each
        final DocumentHashBucket hashBucket = new DocumentHashBucket();
        hashBucket.setNumberDocuments(calls.size());
        final BehaviorSubject<DocumentHashBucket> behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(hashBucket);

        // create the BlockingQueue in order to have a blocking point for the main thread
        final BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        System.out.println("Starting parallel executions");

        // Create an iterable observables
        List<Observable<Integer>> observables = new LinkedList<>();
        for (final Integer i: calls) {
            System.out.println("Adding... "+i);
            observables.add(Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(){
                    Integer res = signHash(behaviorSubject, i);
                    assertTrue(res==i*i,"The result must be the square of the variable");
                    return res;
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())); // subscribeOn => specify the Scheduler on which an Observable will operate
        }

        final Map<String,String> mapResults = new HashMap<>();

        Observable.zip(observables, new Function<Object[], Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Object[] objects) throws Throwable { // Zip observables
                System.out.println("apply()");
                List<String> observables = new LinkedList<>();
                for (Object obj:objects) {
                    System.out.println("Applying... "+obj.toString());
                    observables.add(obj.toString());
                }
                return observables;
            }
        })
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object results){
                        System.out.println("Ending parallel executions");
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable){
                        System.err.println("Error on execution of "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+ throwable.getMessage());
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(Schedulers.from(new Executor() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
                        tasks.add(runnable);// Add a scheduler with executor from the current thread
                    }}))
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                               // The Subscribe operator is the glue that connects an observer to an Observable
                               @Override
                               public void accept(Object onNext) { // Subscribe to the result.
                                   // Put your code that needs to "wait"
                                   for (String x : (List<String>) onNext) {
                                       System.out.println("Results: " + x);
                                       mapResults.put(x, "OK");
                                   }
                               }
                           },
                        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            // The Subscribe operator is the glue that connects an observer to an Observable
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable onError) { // Subscribe to the result.
                                System.err.println("Error on execution in one thread detected on this (main) thread : " + onError.getMessage());
                                onError.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        },
                        new Action() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                System.out.println("onComplete");
                            }
                        });

        System.out.println("[START] TAKE-RUN");
        try {
            tasks.take().run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Error on execution of zip: "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("it's not possible that there is an exception");
        }
        System.out.println("[END] TAKE-RUN");

        assertTrue(mapResults.size()==4);
    }

    private Integer signHash(final BehaviorSubject<DocumentHashBucket> behaviorSubject, Integer number) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [START] doStuff()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(number * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [END] doStuff()");


        DocumentHashBucket hashBucket = behaviorSubject.getValue();
        byte[] numberStringInBytes = ("" + number).getBytes();
        String key = Base64.encodeBase64String(numberStringInBytes);
        hashBucket.getMap().put(key, numberStringInBytes);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" hashBucket.getMap().put new hash : "+key);

        behaviorSubject.blockingForEach(new Consumer<DocumentHashBucket>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(DocumentHashBucket documentHashBucket) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [blockingForEach] DocumentHashBucket is changed and now contains "+documentHashBucket.getMap().size()+" elements");
                synchronized (documentHashBucket){
                    if(documentHashBucket.getNumberDocuments()==documentHashBucket.getMap().size() && documentHashBucket.isCompletedStoreHashes()==false){

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"|> --------- all hashes arrived ---------");
                        // all hashes arrived
                        documentHashBucket.setCompletedStoreHashes(true);

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [START] simulate signHashesOnInternet(..)");
                        try {
                            // simulate network call
                            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        // simulate signing hash on the DocumentHashBucket
                        for(String key : documentHashBucket.getMap().keySet()){
                            int value = Integer.parseInt(new String(documentHashBucket.getMap().get(key)));
                            documentHashBucket.getMap().put(key,(""+(value*value)).getBytes());
                        }
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [END] simulate signHashesOnInternet(..)");

                        // DocumentHashBucket - now hashes are signed
                        documentHashBucket.setCompletedStoreSignedHashes(true);

                        // unlock the blockingForEach
                        behaviorSubject.onComplete();

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"|> --------- all hashes SAVED ---------");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"changed but hashes are: "+documentHashBucket.getMap().size());
                    }
                }// synchronized
            }
        });

        // check that the signing process is applied correctly
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(hashBucket.getMap().get(key),(""+(number*number)).getBytes()));

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [START] doStuff2()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(number * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" [END] doStuff2()");

        assertTrue(hashBucket.getMap().size()==4,"The map must contains 4 elements");
        assertTrue(hashBucket.isCompletedStoreHashes(),"The flag completedStoreHashes must be true");
        assertTrue(hashBucket.isCompletedStoreSignedHashes(),"The flag completedStoreSignedHashes must be true");

        return number*number;
    }
}
```

Log of the execution:

```
Starting parallel executions
Adding... 1
Adding... 2
Adding... 3
Adding... 4
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 [START] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 [START] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 [START] doStuff()
[START] TAKE-RUN
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [START] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 [END] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 hashBucket.getMap().put new hash : MQ==
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 [blockingForEach] DocumentHashBucket is changed and now contains 1 elements
RxNewThreadScheduler-1changed but hashes are: 1
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 [END] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 hashBucket.getMap().put new hash : Mg==
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 [blockingForEach] DocumentHashBucket is changed and now contains 2 elements
RxNewThreadScheduler-2changed but hashes are: 2
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 [END] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 hashBucket.getMap().put new hash : Mw==
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 [blockingForEach] DocumentHashBucket is changed and now contains 3 elements
RxNewThreadScheduler-3changed but hashes are: 3
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [END] doStuff()
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 hashBucket.getMap().put new hash : NA==
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [blockingForEach] DocumentHashBucket is changed and now contains 4 elements
RxNewThreadScheduler-4|> --------- all hashes arrived ---------
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [START] simulate signHashesOnInternet(..)
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [END] simulate signHashesOnInternet(..)
RxNewThreadScheduler-4|> --------- all hashes SAVED ---------
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 [START] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 [START] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [START] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 [START] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 [END] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 [END] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 [END] doStuff2()
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 [END] doStuff2()
apply()
Applying... 1
Applying... 4
Applying... 9
Applying... 16
Ending parallel executions
Results: 1
Results: 4
Results: 9
Results: 16
onComplete
[END] TAKE-RUN


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a possible solution.

It creates a `PublishSubject` that will consume the unsigned hashes after `doStuff()` on each thread.

Then it creates an observable by transforming the `PublishSubject`, which will emit the hashes signed by the API call.

This transformed observable is shared using `replay()`, and it is awaited blockingly in the `signHash` function so that all invocations of `signHash` will wait for the results of the same API call.

```
package com.example.unit;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.observables.ConnectableObservable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;

public class UTestRxJava {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List<Integer> calls = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

        PublishSubject<Map.Entry<String, byte[]>> hashSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        ConnectableObservable<Map<String, byte[]>> connectable = hashSubject
                .toSerialized() // This is needed because we will post to the subject from different threads
                .take(calls.size()) // Wait for all unsigned hashes to arrive
                .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue) // combine all unsigned hashes to a single map
                .flatMapObservable( // use the combined map to create an observable by...
                        unsignedHashes -> Observable.fromCallable(
                                () -> apiCall(unsignedHashes)) // calling the synchronous api with the map
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))  // the api will be performed on the io() scheduler
                .replay(); // all subscribers will get the same api result

        connectable.connect();

        Map<Integer, Integer> result = Observable.fromArray(calls.toArray(new Integer[0]))
                .flatMap((Integer i) ->
                        Observable.fromCallable(() -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(i, signHash(i, hashSubject, connectable.firstOrError())))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))
                .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
                .blockingGet();

        assertEquals(4, result.size());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Result list: " + Arrays.toString(result.entrySet().toArray()));
    }

    private Map<String, byte[]> apiCall(Map<String, byte[]> unsignedHashes) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Calling API with unsigned hashes: " + Arrays.toString(unsignedHashes.entrySet().toArray()));

        Map<String, byte[]> signedHashes = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : unsignedHashes.entrySet()) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(new String(entry.getValue()));
            signedHashes.put(entry.getKey(), ("" + (value * value)).getBytes());
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return signedHashes;
    }

    private Integer signHash(Integer number, PublishSubject<Map.Entry<String, byte[]>> hashSubject, Single<Map<String, byte[]>> hashesSignedByApi) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [START] doStuff()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(number * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [END] doStuff()");

        byte[] numberStringInBytes = ("" + number).getBytes();
        String key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(numberStringInBytes);

        hashSubject.onNext(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(key, numberStringInBytes));
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " hashSubject.onNext with new hash : " + key);

        Map<String, byte[]> signedHashes = hashesSignedByApi.blockingGet();

        // check that the signing process is applied correctly
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(signedHashes.get(key), ("" + (number * number)).getBytes()));

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [START] doStuff2()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(number * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [END] doStuff2()");

        return Integer.valueOf(new String(signedHashes.get(key)));
    }
}
```